# Xcode iOS: how configure GLKit View taken from storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I want to create OpenGL view repainted on demand. I dragged GLKit View from tools page and placed it on the storyboard. Then I joined it to class variable named viewOpenGl. In header file is:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet GLKView *viewOpenGl;
```

In  `viewDidLoad()` I invoke  `SetupOpenGl()` function, which configures this GLKit View, and which should repaint it with blue colour:

```
-(void)SetupOpenGl
{
self.viewOpenGl.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.viewOpenGl.context];
self.viewOpenGl.enableSetNeedsDisplay = true;

glClearColor(0,0,1,1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
[self.viewOpenGl setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

After last three lines rectangle of my GlKit View should be filled with blue, but it is still black.

My question is: why these OpenGl statements does't work? What to configure more in order to draw in GLKitView with OpenGL?

Comment: If this is about iOS, then you are most probably using OpenGL-ES. If this is the case please retag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve the colouring, you need to subclass `GLKView`, and override the `drawRect` method.

**Example:**

.h

```
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@interface CustomBGGLKView : GLKView

@end
```

.m

```
#import "CustomBGGLKView.h"

@implementation CustomBGGLKView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

@end
```

In your storyboard, set the `GLKView` instance to be your `CustomBGGLKView` class.

Than modify your `SetupOpenGl()` function to the following:

```
-(void)setupOpenGl {
    self.viewOpenGl.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];
    self.viewOpenGl.drawableColorFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.viewOpenGl.context];
    self.viewOpenGl.enableSetNeedsDisplay = true;
    [self.viewOpenGl setNeedsDisplay]; 
}
```